# Data studio bug - predefined date range unable to change in view mode

Tags: looker-studio

Seems that I found a bug in DataStudio, unless it is a feature :)

When I created a report where I made default date range : e.g. last 28 days,
Then when somebody or I  want in view mode change the default date setting :  e.g. last 7 days, it still show the predefined time scale.
Any idea ?

here is link to my report
https://datastudio.google.com/s/n2cH8uyFj9s

here is scr:
[image]

Comment: Any idea how markup this Page slides 2 in embded source ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the *Default Date Range* in the chart is currently set to a *Custom Date Range* (Last 28 Days); this does the trick:

1. ***[Time Series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697) Chart***:

   - Set the *Default Date Range* to `Auto`
2. [***Date Range Control***](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6291067):

   - In *Edit Mode*, set the *Default Date Range* to `Last 28 Days`
3. ***(Optional) [Filter Control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144)***

   - Add a *Default Selection* to the `Country` *Filter Control*, for example, `US`

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/bf875fb1-ffaf-4d21-a0b3-27a2f39c9998) and GIF to elaborate:

[image]